How do I install my geckodriver and locate it? Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC
help please. I keep getting this error when I am trying to launch firefox browser.
I am using Eclipse with Java.
My MacOS is 14.5.
Firefox version 126.0.1 (64-bit).
Geckodriver version 0.34.0 (geckodriver-v0.34.0-macos.tar.gz)
I put my geckodriver in Downloads and I can see Firefox in Applications
Downloads folder
Applications folder
I read few articles online but it didn't seem to solve my issue.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: MAC
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'Cicilias-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '2403:4800:280e:9d01:48ca:24b2:de1f:b289%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '14.5', java.version: '17.0.10'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions.getBinary(FirefoxOptions.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at Firefox.runner.main(runner.java:15)

My code is quite simple as below;
package Firefox;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
            "/Users/ciciliaprasetio/Downloads/geckodriver");
        
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

    }

}

Could someone or anyone point me to the right direction or suggest something step by step please?
What I have tried so far:

Installed the geckodriver in the /usr/local/bin (reference)
Changed the key to webdriver.firefox.bin (reference)
Installed the driver in a different way on Mac as in here

Thank you !

I can't tell from your screenshot(s) if you did this already, but you have to untar and unzip that *.tar.gz file to get the actual driver file. Perhaps this can help: What command do I need to unzip/extract a .tar.gz file?

(And then use the full file path and file name in your Java code.)

Hi @andrewJames yes I did that already.

instead of using geckodriver in physical path, you may like to use selenium wdm which is used in selenium 4 onwards. Selenium WDM automatically pick up latest version of your geckodriver and need not to store at physical location and dowlaod latest version every time browser version upgrades.  upgrade your selenium to 4.21.0.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.21.0

Hi I came across this page as well but unsure what to do with it. Any chance you could walk me through? do I need to download something on that page?

are you using maven or gradle

humm..good question. I don't see any pom.xml, build.gradle anywhere
any suggestion where do I need to look? I am using Eclipse.

how  do u use Selenium package
